# don't repeat entry row from two different table

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

i created two database (php using XAMPP) one for employee (id, name) and another for administrator(id, name).
the id in the two tables are primary key, i need to build a relation between the two table where id don't repeat .for example :admin(1,a)uses id = 1 which should not be used in the employee table

please help

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. Try to explain what you want to do. Not the technical _how_ you are trying to do it, but your goal.

Comment: and now did you are understand ??

Comment: Not really. I do understand that you want to store admins in one and other persons in another table. But it is not clear what type of relation you want to model and why you want to store the persons in different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normative approach to this problem is to use a *single* table. That makes it very easy to keep the `id` values distinct.

You can include a *discriminator* column that indicates whether a row represents an "employee" or an "administrator". In your example, there's two possible values.

```
 CREATE TABLE employee 
 ( id     INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'pk'
 , ename  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 , admin  TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'boolean'
 )
```

Some example data, to illustrate:

```
 id  ename             admin
 --- ---------------- -------
 42  Barney Rubble     0 
 43  Fred Flintstone   0 
 17  Mr. Slate         1
```

Sample queries:

```
-- select "employee" rows
SELECT id, ename FROM employee WHERE admin=0

-- select "administrator" rows
SELECT id, ename FROM employee WHERE admin
```

---

If you need two *separate* tables, that you asked about

Bottom line is that there is no declarative constraint available in MySQL that will enforce the `id` values between the two tables to be "distinct" from one another.

To do that, you would have to "roll your own" solution. And that solution is not trivial, it can be rather involved.

There are some solutions to simpler problems, automatically generating unique `id` values. But to actually enforce uniqueness, there is no simple way to do that.

Is your goal to just enforce a constraint, such that INSERT and UPDATE statements will throw an error if they attempt to violate the constraint, you are going to need to write triggers.